# TypeScript error: Cannot write file 'index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file

Tags: typescript

I have issue when run `tsc`

```
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
```

my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "newLine": "LF",
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "pretty": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },

  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings"
  ]
}
```

This issue solved when:

1. exclude `index.ts` in `tsconfig`
2. run `tsc index.ts`
3. Turn `declaration` off in `tsconfig`
4. rename `index` to another name!

I have same issue when change typescript main file in package.json
for example: rename index.ts to foo.ts

change `package.json` to

```
"typescript": {
  "main": "foo.ts"
}
```

tsc error:

```
error TS5055: Cannot write file 'index.d.ts' because it would overwrite input file.
```

content of file no mater, any code content has same issue!

What can i do for fix it ?

Source code: https://github.com/AliMD/Node.js-Telegram-Bot-API/tree/v0.0.2-0
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I excluded `index.ts` in `tsconfig` temporary to solve this issue and run `tsc index.ts` separately when `index.ts` changed! :(

Comment: maybe you have a reference to `index.d.ts` in your code somewhere, then when you compile, the compiler thinks that `index.d.ts` is part of the source and therefor throw that error. just a thought.

Comment: What happens if you compile with out the `"declaration": true`?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: there is no error when declaration set to false

Comment: I report it as an [issue to typescript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8468)

Comment: file can be deleted and issue remain, i don`t want the outDir and its not related to this issue, i think you dont know the answer and try to collect some point at stackoverflow

Comment: you don't get points on comments, but you're right, I don't know the answer, but I'm asking questions/making suggestions in order to try and help you solve or find workaround your problem until it's solved. You're welcome.  And the outDir can be related to the issue as it separates the source from the output, and then it shouldn't complain about writing on a source file, maybe, just a thought, but maybe it won't work, damn, won't get my precious points.

Comment: outDir not fixed the issue!

Comment: That's too bad. Though from the correspondence in the ticket you opened it seems that (a) everyone there suggest similar things to what I suggested (they are probably looking for stackoverflow points as well, bastards) and (b) that I was right. You do reference that `.d.ts` file with that import of yours.  I'd expect an apology, but from what you write and how you write it (from what I've been reading so far) it will be stupid to expect such a thing. I'd wish you best of luck, but honestly don't care.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your example folder you wrote `import * as test from '../'`
see https://github.com/AliMD/Node.js-Telegram-Bot-API/blob/v0.0.2/examples/test-server.ts#L1

It should load your `index.ts`, `index.d.ts`, or `package.json` "typings" field.
And that's the issue. Your `package.json` does say that `index.d.ts` is the definition file for this package, see https://github.com/AliMD/Node.js-Telegram-Bot-API/blob/v0.0.2/package.json#L9
so `import * as test from '../'` will load `package.json`, load typings field and then load `index.d.ts` and it causes the problem.

**Two solutions**

- Import index file instead of root folder (recommended approach)
  e.g. `import * as test from '../index'`; or,
- Move output to a different folder
  e.g. `\lib\index.d.ts`.

In both solutions you should load the target file and not the folder. Since you're not loading the root folder anymore the problem will be solved.

Comment: Links broken, you better to copy that code snippet that use URLs

Comment: @Al-Mothafar Thank you, i updated the links, as you see i wrote the codes and also link the source for more information

Comment: Worth noting that the same applies if you import from “./“ and happen to be at the top level, which is helpful when searching for this pattern of use

Answer (score 15):

Perahaps a better approach is to exclude the `target` directory from your build.  The key is including the same directory in both the `outDir` and `exclude` keys:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es6",
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "outDir": "target",
        "declaration": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "target"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case I was missing `"include": ["./src/**/*.ts"]` in tsconfig.json even though I had set the following:

```
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "./build",
        "rootDir": "./src"
    },
```

Typescript was probably confused as to which files it needed to include and probably thought my file that was built in `./build/index.d.ts` was an input file.

Answer (score 4):

Many thanks to everyone else for their answers, for me however the problem was a lot simpler (and stupider). I had let WebStorm select the best import statement for me and overlooked that it included a file from the "dist" directory (this is what I have my output set to.

Once that cause was found the error made much more sense as it was indeed trying to write to the output file that was being used as it's input.

Comment: I had similar problem, VSCode was doing auto imports, and I overlooked one of them was from dist directory.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `include` to my configuration solved the problem for me.

```json
  {
    "compilerOptions": {
        /* ... */
    },
    "include": ["src"],
    "exclude": ["**/*.test.*"]
  }
```

As said in the [doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#exclude),  *`exclude` specifies an array of filenames or patterns that should be skipped when resolving `include`.*

I deduce that `exclude` can't work if `include` hasn't been defined.

Answer (score -1):

I had this very same problem, and it was super simple to fix. I deleted node_modules, then deleting the typings folder.

in package.json I have these in

```
scripts: {
    ...
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "typings": "typings"
    ...
}
```

then ran the commands:

```sh
npm install
npm run tsc
npm run typings install
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted. But in the last 6 years, this error has occurred for numerous reasons. This answer helped out with my issue, and it is used as a possible answer that could be tried without ruining your solution. Just because it didn't work for you doesn't mean it's not a possible solution.