# Typescript compiler can't skip imported js file

Tags: angular, typescript, import, tsc, tsconfig

I've just started typescript with angular2 and I've run into the following problem.
I started with the angular2 quickstart project and it worked fine, until I tried to import a plain javascript file.
I am using the import statement as follows

```
import * as myModule from './mymodule.js';
```

Also I added the `allowJs: true` to the tsconfig.json file to accept the javascript file as an import.
The following error is given by the compiler:

> error TS5055: Cannot write file '.../mymodule.js' because it would overwrite input file.

As far as I understand the typescript compiler should not compile this file, because it is already in javascript, but for some reason I cannot exclude this from compilation.

I tried adding the file to the `exclude: []` array in tsconfig.json, but because it is imported in one of my .ts files this is not taken into consideration (at least that's what I understood from the typescript docs).

**My question is how can I compile my project with that file included? Is there a setting that I'm missing? Or something wrong with my approach?**

Any help or advice is appreciated as this is starting to drive me crazy

### **Additional info**

I'm using the following tsconfig file:

```
{
   "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es5",
      "module": "commonjs",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
      "experimentalDecorators": true,
      "lib": [ "es2015", "dom" ],
      "noImplicitAny": true,
      "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
   }
}
```

I'm building my project running the

```
npm run build
```

from a console. Which is a script in the package.json file that looks like this:

```
"scripts": {
   "build": "tsc -p src/",
...
```

After the modifications suggested by @Seamus below, the same error happens.

**But**

if I just run in the console

```
tsc -p src/
```

The error I get is different:

> error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'mymodule'

This looks like it find the module, if I do it manually, but then the question is, why does it not work with the `npm run build`? Is it doing something differently?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37013665/typescript-error-cannot-write-file-index-d-ts-because-it-would-overwrite-inpu it is refering to the same error for a d.ts file though

Comment: @suraj Thanks, I've already seen that, but that did not help, unfortunately.

Comment: Do you have different versions of TypeScript installed globally and locally? Try `npm list typescript` and `npm list -g typescript`.

Comment: @Seamus I'm getting there :D So I updated the typescript I had in the local project, so now both are the same. Now the error is the same too: mymodule.d.ts is not a module

Comment: @Seamus You are my HERO! I mispelled the declare module, but now it works. Can't thank you enough!

Comment: Excellent. Glad to hear it. Yeah, when you do `npm run somescript` it will look for locally installed modules first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler option [allowJs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) will:

> > Allow JavaScript files to be compiled.

For `commonjs` you will need a module declaration like this:

**mymodule.d.ts**

```
declare module "mymodule";
```

And in your source where you import:

```
/// <reference path="mymodule.d.ts"/>
import * as myModule from 'mymodule';
```

See ["Working with Other JavaScript Libraries"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#working-with-other-javascript-libraries) in the documentation.

Comment: If I don't specify the .js at the end, the compiler, does not find my module: error TS2307 cannot find module './mymodule'

Comment: @Seamus Thanks for taking the time and answering me. This still won't fix it unfortunately. The same error is shows up. I also tried to put my js file inside a `node_modules` folder, since according to https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html the compiler should search there, but still no luck...

Comment: @zolipapa What module system are you targeting? In `tsconfig.json`, what is the `module` property set to under `compilerOptions`?

Comment: @Seamus edited the question for you to see! I'm using the one that came with the angular quickstart: `node`

Comment: @Seamus Sorry, the module system I'm targeting is 'commonjs', the module resolution is 'node'

Comment: @zolipapa OK, it's a little different for commonjs. I'll update the answer and link to documentation.

Comment: @Seamus Please see my edit, I updated the question with a few more details that I found just now

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know this is old, but I had this problem and I think I figured out a way around it (possibly partly due to an Angular update).

To start:

1. Upgrade your Angular to the latest version (`5.1`).
2. Upgrade your TypeScript to the latest supported version (`4.*`, as of the time of the writing -- not `5.*`)
3. You probably need `allowJs: true` in your config file.

Run `ng serve --aot` or `ng build --watch=auto --aot` You should see the above error and be unable to access your site.

Open one of the .ts file that's part of your app and make a small change (such as adding a single space) and then save the file.

Your app should compile!

(The `--watch=auto` and `--aot` flags are critical for this workaround, as far as I can tell)